# Convergence in $L_p$ with $\sigma$-finite measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I have a problem about convergence in $L_p$ spaces, and I really not understand why I need of a specific hypothesis.

> Let be $L_p(X,\Omega,\mu)$ a measure space, where $\mu$ is
>   $\sigma$-finite, $p\in [1,\infty)$. If $\phi: X\to \Bbb{K}$ is
>   mensurable and $M_\phi: L_p\to L_p$ is a map defined by
>
> $$M_\phi(f)=\phi f$$
>
> since that $\phi f\in L_p,$ show that $M_\phi$ is a closed operator.

It is necessary that $\mu$ be $\sigma$-finite? Or I can just to apply the Riesz-Fischer Theorem to solve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigma finiteness is not necessary.

Assume $f_n \to f $ and $g_n := M_\phi f_n \to g $ with convergence in $L^p $. We want to show $g =M_\phi f $. Switching to a subsequence, we can assume $f_{n_k} \to f $ almost everywhere and $g_{n_k} \to g $ almost everywhere. But this implies 
$$
g (x) = \lim_k g_{n_k}(x) = \lim_k \phi (x) f_{n_k}(x) = \phi (x) f (x) =( M_\phi f)(x)
$$
almost everywhere,  as desired.